# Does foreach work on Iterator?

Tags: glib, vala, libgee

```
using Gee;

int main (string[] args) {
        ArrayList<string> list = new ArrayList<string>();

        list.add ("a");
        list.add ("b");
        list.add ("c");

        foreach (var s in list.filter (s => s > "a")) stdout.printf (@"s\n");

        return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile, because `Traversable<G>.filter` doesn't return an object with an "iterate()" method, but an `Iterator<G>`.

Is there any way to get `foreach` working on an iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gee iterators/Traversables implement [foreach](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gee-1.0/Gee.Traversable.@foreach) as a method:

```
list.filter (s => s > "a").foreach (s => { stdout.printf (@"s\n"); return true; });
```